# bad_Access exception when typing in UITextView

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I don't know what is wrong with this code; when i start typing in the UITextView, the program terminates with exc_Bad_Access exception.

```
UIView *toolbar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 44)];
toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
UITextView *sendTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 9, 240, 26)];
sendTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
sendTextView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
sendTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
[toolbar addSubview:sendTextView];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

The above code is inside the viewDidLoad method of a UIViewController which has a UIScrollView as its view.

Answer (score 0):

Putting an editable text view in a toolbar seems strange. (What do you do when the user wants to edit it? Move it up above the keybaord? I wouldn't expect a toolbar to move OR to contain an editable field.) Nevertheless, I'd be surprised if doing that caused EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Your problem is more likely in code that actually runs when you're typing, such as one of the text view delegate methods. If you can't find anything there, please post the stack trace at the time of the crash and code for the method that was actually running at the time.

**Update:** After you pointed it out in your comment, I see that you're setting the toolbar as the input accessory view for `sendTextView` *and* adding it to the view controller's view. I'd guess that what's happening here is that when you start editing the text view, the text view adds the toolbar to the keyboard's view without first removing it from the view controller's view. A given view can only be part of one view hierarchy at a time; adding it to your view *and* using it as the input accessory view won't work. If you look at [Apple's sample code for using an accessory view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html) you'll find that the view used as the accessory isn't part of the normal view hierarchy.

Comment: Because the toolbar (which is actually a UIView) is inputAccessoryView of the textView, it move above the keyboard when the textView activates, like the Messages iPhone application.

Comment: Right -- I missed that you were both setting the toolbar as the input accessory view *and* adding it to the view. A view can only have one parent, it can't be part of two view hierarchies at the same time, so don't add it as a subview of your view controller's view if you want to use it as the input accessory view. If you want both, I think you'll need two toolbars.

Comment: I downloaded the Apple's KeyboardAccessory project and run it in xcode but that shows the same error as soon as i start typing in the textView. I have xcode 4.2 Build 4D199

Comment: Strange -- that project works fine for me, both as is and with a text field added to the accessory view.

Comment: God! the problem was with the iOS 4.3 simulator. I changed the simulator to 5.0 and now it works fine. Thanks for your help.